# After exporting from blender to unity3d: How to solve this warning ? Can't calculate tangents, because mesh 'Circle' doesn't contain normals

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I created in blender 4.0 a circle.

In blender:

Add > Mesh > Circle

added to it more vertices and then exported it to unity3d.
Then I did:  Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside.

The circle:

[image: circle]

Next , saved it and exporting by doing File >  Export > FBX (.fbx)

[image: export]

in unity3d in the editor I dragged the file to the Assets one dragged it I'm getting the warning:

Can't calculate tangents, because mesh 'Circle' doesn't contain normals

I thought by doing in blender Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside it should add normals.
but the problem in unity not solved.

and when I dragged the file to the unity editor Assets there is no circle at all.

[image: after dragging the file to the unity editor assets.]

Comment: As you already [asked a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520054/when-adding-a-new-property-in-blender-and-then-export-as-fbx-then-when-importing) where this seems to be resolved .. can we consider this question as resolved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When adding a new property in blender and then export as fbx then when importing to unity the new property not show in unity editor. how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520054/when-adding-a-new-property-in-blender-and-then-export-as-fbx-then-when-importing)