# When adding a new property in blender and then export as fbx then when importing to unity the new property not show in unity editor. how to fix?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

In blender I pressed the N key and then on the right side I selected Tools > Workspace > Custom Properties > then clicked on the + New and gave a name to the new property.

Same I did on the side in the Object tab also added new property.

Then saved and in the menu: File > Export > FBX (.fbx) and in the export window I checked the checkbox:  Custom Properties.

but then when dragging the file to the unity editor I see the model but not see the new propety.

[image: blender settings]

and in unity3d editor after importing:
I don't see the new property Fill Amount:

[image: the new property Fill Amount not exist in unity after importing]

Comment: Does Unity's build in FBX importer support custom properties?

Comment: I don't think so tbh .. you will probably have to write your own importer to handle that! Like e.g. this one https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-import-user-defined-attributes-from-fbx-files.409877 .. or just [search online](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+FBX+import+custom+properties)

Comment: tbh i cant see in the blender screen what you looking for, so, it is hard to advise